# How to get CData from html using beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to get a value from a webpage. In the source code of the webpage, the data is in CDATA format and also comes from a jQuery. I have managed to write the below code which gets a large amount of text, where the index 21 contains the information I need. However, this output is large and not in a format I understand. Within the output I need to isolate and output `"redshift":"0.06"` but dont know how. what is the best way to solve this.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://wis-tns.weizmann.ac.il/object/2020aclx"  

html = requests.get(link).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
res = soup.findAll('b')

print soup.find_all('script')[21]
```

Comment: Check [CData](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#comments-and-other-special-strings)

Answer (score 1):

It *can* be done using the current approach you have. However, I'd advise against it. There's a neater way to do it by observing that the redshift value is present in a few convenient places on the page itself.

The following approach should work for you. It looks for `table`s on the page with the `class` "atreps-results-table" -- of which there are two. We take the second such table and look for the table cell with the class "cell-redshift". Then, we just print out its text content.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

link = 'https://wis-tns.weizmann.ac.il/object/2020aclx'
html = requests.get(link).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
tab = soup.find_all('table', {'class': 'atreps-results-table'})[1]
redshift = tab.find('td', {'class': 'cell-redshift'})
print(redshift.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simply:

```
soup.select_one('div.field-redshift > div.value>b').text
```

Answer (score 0):

If you view the Page Source of the URL, you will find that there are two script elements that are having CDATA. But the script element in which you are interested has jQuery in it. So you have to select the script element based on this knowledge. After that, you need to do some cleaning to get rid of CDATA tags and jQuery. Then with the help of json library, convert JSON data to Python Dictionary.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

page = requests.get('https://wis-tns.weizmann.ac.il/object/2020aclx')
htmlpage = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
scriptelements = htmlpage.find_all('script')
for script in scriptelements:
  if 'CDATA' in script.text and 'jQuery' in script.text:
    scriptcontent = script.text.replace('<!--//--><![CDATA[//>', '').replace('<!--', '').replace('//--><!]]>', '').replace('jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings,', '').replace(');', '')
    break
jsondata = json.loads(scriptcontent)
print(jsondata['objectFlot']['plotMain1']['params']['redshift'])
```